# LLC v. W-2 Taxes when filing in Florida

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, florida

I'm considering working as a contractor in Florida.

Currently I'm a W-2 contractor, but considering a Corp-to-Corp contract since it's a higher rate.

Just now I read Florida's Tax Page - http://dor.myflorida.com/dor/taxes/corporate.html.

However, if I were to file as an LLC or LLP (not clear to me which one to choose), would I still face 0% taxes on my personal income as I currently enjoy as a W-2 employee?

Answer (score 2):

LLC is a Limited Liability Company.

LLP is a Limited Liability Partnership.

You cannot make an LLP of a single partner - you must have 2 or more. You can, however, make a single-member LLC.

As to the taxation - that same web page you linked to in your question has this to say:

> A single member LLC disregarded for Florida and federal income tax
>   purposes is not required to file a separate Florida corporate income
>   tax return. The income must be reported on the owner’s return if the
>   single member LLC is owned, directly or indirectly, by a corporation.
>   The corporation must file Florida Form F-1120, reporting its own
>   income and the income of the single member LLC, even if the only
>   activity of the corporation is ownership of the single member LLC.

I.e.: if your LLC is classified as a disregarded entity and you (the individual) are the only member - you will not be required to pay Florida income taxes.

Just to remind you - there's no such thing "W2 contractor". There's "employee". Once you stop being employee and become a contractor - you lose some benefits and protections. You will also have to pay your full FICA (as an employee you're only paying half, your employer pays the other half). That is the reason why contractors get higher hourly pay.

Answer (score 1):

from your linked page

`A single member LLC disregarded for Florida and federal income tax purposes is not required to file a separate Florida corporate income tax return. The income must be reported on the owner’s return if the single member LLC is owned, directly or indirectly, by a corporation. The corporation must file Florida Form F-1120, reporting its own income and the income of the single member LLC, even if the only activity of the corporation is ownership of the single member LLC.`

this is more in line with the tax code across the country and the federal government, which also disregards single member LLCs for tax purposes.

basically, disregarded entities mean that those entities do not file tax, and whatever your INDIVIDUAL income tax burden is all that applies. So if in Florida you would not have an individual income tax burden, then you still wouldn't have one